# Android Notification does not show

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

guys I used this code to show notification, but today I tried to create a new application, and does not show notification, I have no clue what is going on. I send notification from firebase, and I don't show notification. Any idea ?

On emulator it show notification, and not in my Samsung A8 (2018), I have same code in other app it works great.

```
  private void showSmallNotification( int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = builder
                .setChannelId(Constants.TOPIC_GLOBAL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(100, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Notification channel? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String CHANNEL_ID = "1";
    String CHANNEL_NAME = "Notification";

    Notification.Builder notification;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.trial),
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .build());
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
    } else {
        notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        notification.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.trial));
    }
    notification.setContentTitle(Title)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100})
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentText(ContentText)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.green))
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_purple_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(CHANNEL_ID, 1, notification.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you can deliver the notification on Android 8.0 and higher, you must register your app's notification channel with the system by passing an instance of NotificationChannel to createNotificationChannel(). So the following code is blocked by a condition on the SDK_INT version:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java) article.